# Define a caption figure name style

Tags: captions, tufte

I'm trying to make my captions look like this:

[image: My wanted caption style]

But without any success until now. Does somebody have any idea to make my caption name look like this? I'm working in a Tufte book environment and I'm using the pdfLaTeX compiler. Here is a minimal code of my project:

```
\documentclass[justified,notoc,numbers]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm, mathtools, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

%-----------FOR DEMO-----------
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
\graphicspath{{graphics/}}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\lstset{language=C} 

%=======================================================
%                      FONT STYLE
%=======================================================
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}

%=======================================================
%                       COUNTERS
%=======================================================
\newcounter{theexample}[section]
\newcounter{thedefinition}[section]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
%=======================================================
%                       COLORS
%=======================================================
\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}

%=======================================================
%               TITLES & CAPTION OPTIONS
%=======================================================

\titleformat*{\section}{\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\titlespacing{\section}{0cm}{0cm}{0cm}[0cm]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0}{*0}
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{0pt}{*2}{*2}

%=======================================================
%                   MY ENVIRONMENTS
%=======================================================
\newenvironment{demo}{\textit{Démonstration: }}{\hfill \faSquare}

\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{defn}{Définition \stepcounter{thedefinition}\thesection.\arabic{thedefinition}}{
breakable,
colback=white!80!gray,
colframe=black,
colbacktitle=black,
coltitle=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
enhanced,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=5mm,yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
top = 3mm,
separator sign={\ -}
}{th}

\newcommand\remarque[1]{
    \marginnote{\justify
    \tikzpicture[baseline={(title.base)}]
      \node[inner sep=5pt, align=justify,text width=4cm,drop shadow={shadow yshift=-5pt,shadow xshift=5pt,black},fill=white] (box) {\vskip5pt \nointerlineskip #1};
      \node[right=5pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=5pt] (title) at (box.north west) {\scshape\normalsize\bfseries\color{myColor}Remarque};
      \draw[draw=myColor,very thick](title.west)--(box.north west)--(box.south west)--(box.south east)--(box.north east)--(title.east);
      \fill[myColor]([yshift=-10pt]box.north west)--+(-5pt,-5pt)--+(0pt,-10pt);
   \endtikzpicture}
}

\newtcolorbox{exmp}[1][]{
  breakable,
  enhanced,
  borderline west={2pt}{0pt}{myColor},
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
  coltitle={black},
  title= {\textcolor{myColor}{Exemple  \stepcounter{theexample}\thesection.\arabic{theexample}:} #1\\},
  attach title to upper,
  right=0pt,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  frame hidden,
  colback=white!80!gray,
}

\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{summary}{en bref}{
  breakable,
  separator sign none,
  breakable,
  boxrule=0.6pt,
  colback=white,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  colframe=myColor,
  colbacktitle=myColor,
  fonttitle= \scshape \Large \bfseries,
  coltitle={white},
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  fontupper=\footnotesize
}{the}



\title{test - tex.stackexchange.com}
\author[Author Name \& Firstname]{Author Name \& Firstname}


%=======================================================
%                       MACROS
%=======================================================
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al}.}
\newcommand{\ie}{\textbf{\textit{i}.\textit{e}. }}
\newcommand{\eg}{\textbf{\textit{e}.\textit{g}. }}
\newcommand{\cfr}{\textit{cfr}. }
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}} %For right d on integrals & derivatives
\newcommand{\X}{\mathcal{X}} %For probabilities notation
\newcommand{\Y}{\mathcal{Y}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathcal{Z}}


\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}


%=======================================================
%                       GEOMETRY
%=======================================================
\geometry{
  left=15mm,                    % left margin
  textwidth=140mm,              % main text block
  headsep=10mm,
  headheight = 0mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,             % gutter between main text block and margin notes
  marginparwidth=50mm,          % width of margin notes
  bottom = 1.5cm, 
  top = 1.7cm
}

%=======================================================
%                     HEADER/FOOTER
%=======================================================
\pagestyle{fancy}{
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Author Name \& Firstname}
\lhead{\textsc{test} - tex.stackexchange.com}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

}

%=======================================================
%               CODE INSERTION OPTIONS
%=======================================================
\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
mathescape=true,
frame=single, 
captionpos = b
}
%=======================================================
%               NEW WORD CAESURA
%=======================================================
\hyphenation{sto-cha-sti-ques}

%=======================================================
%                       DOCUMENT
%=======================================================
\begin{document}

%---------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{titlepage}
    \fontfamily{pag}
    \begin{center}
        \noindent\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[draft]{example-image}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \colorbox{grey}{
        \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
            \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
                \vspace{0.2cm}
                \begin{center}
                \fontsize{13pt}{0pt}\selectfont
                \text{TEST - tex.stackexchange.com}\\
                \fontsize{50pt}{0pt}\selectfont\bfseries
                \vspace{0.3cm}\underline{Base project}\end{center} {\Huge2019}
                \vspace{0.7cm}
            }
        }
    }

    \vfill
    %------------------------------------------------
    %   Author name and information
    %------------------------------------------------

    \parbox[t]{1.2\textwidth}{
        \raggedleft
        \large
        {\Large Author}\\[4pt]
        University\\
        \hfill\rule{0.2\linewidth}{1pt}
    }

\end{titlepage}
%---------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{fullwidth}
 \lipsum[5]
\end{fullwidth}
\section{Chapter 1:}
\lipsum[2]
\lipsum[3]
\remarque{\lipsum[1]}
\begin{defn}{DEFINITION TITLE}{DEFLABEL}
\lipsum[4]
\end{defn}
\begin{exmp}
\lipsum[1]
\end{exmp}
\begin{summary}{}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{summary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please make your code example minimal. it should content only relevant packages (`\documentclass`, graphicx` and `caption`/which will solve your problem/ and example of figure in document body. remove all other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tufte` uses a special definition for the caption, one can adjust it like this:

```
\documentclass[justified,notoc,numbers]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm, mathtools, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{theorem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.9}
\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 1.0}


\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par%
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup%
    \@parboxrestore%
    \if@minipage%
      \@setminipage%
    \fi%
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
    \colorbox{myColor}{\color{white}\noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:} \ignorespaces#3\par%
    %\@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{SteelBlue}
 \DeclareCaptionFormat{shadelabel}{\colorbox{shadecolor}{\rule[-0.8ex]{0pt}{3ex}\,\color{white}#1~#2\kern -0.3em}~#3 }%
\captionsetup{format =shadelabel, font ={sf, bf}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{cahier}
\caption{Le cahier d’une écolière}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]